# How to write outputs of python unit test framework file into .xml file to visualize on jenkins?

Tags: python, xml, unit-testing, jenkins

I have a python file testing.py consisting of following:

```
import subprocess
import unittest
DETACHED_PROCESS = 0x00000008
def open_exe(file,mode):
    if mode == 1:
        if type(file) is str:
            object = subprocess.Popen([file],creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS,shell=True)
        if object.pid is None:
            return 0
        else:
            print "Process id ", object.pid
            return 1
   if mode == 2:
       if type(file) is str:
           object = subprocess.Popen([file,"-configuration=" + "Other_base_0x1010.def"], creationflags=DETACHED_PROCESS,shell=True)
       if object.pid is None:
            return 0
       else:
            print "Process id ", object.pid
            return 1
    class testmyfunctions(unittest.TestCase):
       def test_contains_simple_true(self):
          self.assertEqual(open_exe("D:\\learning\\development\\MY_base.exe",1),1)              
      def test_first_process(self):
          self.assertEqual(open_exe("D:\\learning\\Projects\\Other_base.exe", 2), 1)     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This testing.py file is actualy opening two .exe's and then i have made two test cases.My question is how do i write the output of testing.py to xml file which are to be visualized on jenkins? Are there some commands ? Atleast suggest me from where to start.

Comment: try the tag `--junit-xml unit_test_results.xml` and check this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/junit-xml)

Answer (score 1):

first, install xmlrunner into your slave node. You can refer to  [this link](https://github.com/xmlrunner/unittest-xml-reporting) along with how to use it with your unittest.

second. Back to jenkins,you need to set up a job with 2 steps:
**step1**: "Execute Shell" to execute your unittest, make sure you use xmlrunner to generate the xml output.
**step2**: "Add post-build action" ==>"Publish JUnit test report" and just put your report path(generated in step1) there.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `nosetests` as your test runner.  It is compatible with standard `unittest` tests, and has various output format options.

see: [nose.readthedocs.org](https://nose.readthedocs.org/)

To create JUnitXML, you would specify `--with-xunit` on the command line.  So to run your tests, simply do:

```
$ nosetests --with-xunit
```

This will run your test suite, and generate a file named nosetests.xml in the current working directory.